# How do you set a default font family when using a pre-made flutter theme?

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, material-design, themes

I am trying to set the default font for my Flutter app. I've read all the documentation and followed it, however, the docs say to use `theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Example'),`. The issue I have is that I'm using `theme: ThemeData.light(),` not `theme: ThemeData(),`. Putting the `fontFamily: 'Example'` in the brackets after `.light()` doesn't work.

So my question is, how do you set the default font for this pre-made flutter theme?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of ThemeData.light() (what it acutally is doing) says [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.light.html):

```
factory ThemeData.light() => ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light);
```

So you could achieve the light theme with the font of your choice with:

```
ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, fontFamily: 'Example')
```